# Auto scroll to search input field and do not show old search options on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

So I have a search input field on my website.

```
 <input type="search" id="searchfield">
```

When I click on it on mobile(Chrome browser) the keyboard appears. So I scroll up to make it surely visible.

```
$('input').on('focus', function () {
    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        document.body.scrollTop = this.getBoundingClientRect().top - screen.height / 4;
    }
});
```

But it can show the old inputs for the search field in a menu and it makes a scrolldown about a half page and hides the kinda whole page behind it.

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl4e4.png)

I hope you can help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You only have to turn off the [autocomplete attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp).

`<input type="search" id="searchfield" autocomplete="off"/>`